# Three.js not rendering texture on external model properly

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a very realistic scene using Three.js. So far I have implemented mouse controls, loading model from Maya and I came to applying textures. The code works however, as it can be seen on the images below the textures don't fill the box as one would expect. I assume the problem is because each face of the model is filled separately, which occurred to me when I displayed my model as in wireframe mode.

My UV values look like this :

> [[0.375,0,0.625,0,0.375,0.25,0.625,0.25,0.375,0.5,0.625,0.5,0.375,0.75,0.625,0.75,0.375,1,0.625,1,0.875,0,0.875,0.25,0.125,0,0.125,0.25]]

[image: Model]

```
function init() {

        // renderer

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 5;

        cameraControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        cameraControls.target.set(0, 0, 0);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
        scene.add( light );

        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/box_texture.jpg') 
        } );       

        group = new THREE.Object3D();

        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('models/cube_1.js', modelLoadedCallback);

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function modelLoadedCallback(geometry) {

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        group.add(mesh);
    //     scene.add (new THREE.Mesh (geometry,
    // new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial ({ color: 0x000000, wireframe: true })));
        scene.add (new THREE.Mesh (geometry, material));
        scene.add( group );

}

function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        render();

}

function animate() {

        var delta = clock.getDelta();

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        cameraControls.update(delta);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: the uv coords of your cube are wrong.

Comment: To further explore gaitats remark, cube_1.js contains incorrect UV coordinates. So assuming the box looks ok inside Maya, it's likely your export from Maya went wrong. Did you try triangulating the object before export? That's always a quick thing to try, as exporters often don't do this right or at all.

Comment: I haven't tried triangulating, just exported the OBJ from Maya and used their Python script to convert. I'll try your suggestion and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried triangulating and quadrangulating the model but the result is still the same. To keep things simple I drew a basic cube and used python script to export it to Three.js 
I'm not an expert in 3D modeling so I'm not really sure what these UVs actually mean. I've updated my question and added UV array values maybe you can check it out and tell me if there are any mistakes there.

Answer (score 0):

It can be helpful

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/box_texture.jpg') ;
```

and add:

```
texture.flipY = false;
```